# Should I always use isset() for URL arguments?

Tags: php, isset

Here is my code:

```
    $order_newest = $order_votes = $order_featured = $order_frequent = '';
    switch ($_GET['o']) {
        case 'newest':
            $order_newest = 'order_active';
            break;
        case 'votes':
            $order_votes = 'order_active';
            break;
        case 'featured':
            $order_featured = 'order_active';
            break;  
        case 'frequent':
            $order_frequent = 'order_active';
            break;                                          
        default:
            $order_newest = 'order_active';
            break;
    }
```

It throws following error when `o` argument isn't exist in the URL:

> Notice: Undefined index: o in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 71

I can fix the problem by adding this condition:

```
$order_newest = $order_votes = $order_featured = $order_frequent = '';
if ( isset($_GET['o']) ) {
    switch ($_GET['o']) {
        .
        .
        .
    }
} else {
    $order_newest = 'order_active';
}
```

But I guess this isn't the right way. Because in this case I have to add lots of conditions contain `isset()` function.

Anyway, is there any better approach to handle that?

Comment: where is the problem? yes for pages where o is not set isset will work but without it everytime you go to a page without o in url this error will pop up, and for isset its one line extra

Answer (score 0):

Use [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php). As example:

```
$order = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'o');

switch ($order) {
  // ...
```